# Decode a UTF-16 string into ASCII

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a program written in C that will create a WCHAR (UTF-16) and send it to a python script. It will receive it as:

```
'63006400630064006300640063006400'
```

I want to print it out as:

```
cdcdcdcd
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially here you want to first decode a base-16 encoded byte string to a byte string, and then to decode it from UTF-16 LE.

Fortunately, all this stuff is already provided by the standard library, so this is essentially a one-liner:

```
def decode_base16_UTF16(s):
    import base64
    return base64.b16decode(s, True).decode('UTF-16LE')
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't vouch for the performance of doing it this way but you can get a bytes object from a string of hex like so:

```
data = bytes.fromhex("63006400630064006300640063006400")
```

From there you can decode it as usual:

```
my_string = data.decode("utf-16le")
```

Here's the reference for fromhex: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex (there's a fromhex class method for a number of the basic data types actually).